# Why I am unable to assign an iterator with vector index values?

Tags: c++11, stdvector

Sample code

```
std::vector<int> testvectr;
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
testvectr.push_back(10);
it = testvectr.begin(); // method 1 - works 
it = &(testvectr[0]); //  method 2  - errors as  binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type '_Ty *'
```

Why its throwing error? I am trying to assign a  vector index. So later I can call it by *it. 
But I didn't understand the error behind it. Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector<T>::iterator` is not necessarily `T *`. If you have a pointer `p` to an element of a vector and want to get an iterator to that same element, you can use the following pointer arithmetic:

```
auto it = v.begin() + (p - v.data());
```